# Want to read Worksheets from a workbook using Python Wincom32

Tags: python, excel

I want to read Worksheets from a workbook using Python Wincom32 module but not able to read it if number of sheets are more.
For Example i have an excel workbook with total 150 worksheets in it and i am trying to read 89th Excel worksheet using Python Wincom32 module but it is giving me some sheet name which is not present in the Excel Workbook at all.
I am using below python code

```
import win32com.client
dispatch = win32com.client.Dispatch
excel = dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.visible = 1
wb = excel.Workbooks.open('<PATH TO EXCEL>')
count = wb.Sheets.count # count stores total number of worksheets present
print count  
ws_name = wb.Sheets[ 89 ].name 
""" This is supposed to read the name of 89th Worksheet instead it is giving me some garbage
    name  """
print ws_name
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure your wb has 150 worksheets? What does the count variable prints?

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the right workbook? If it's giving you some sheet name that isn't present in the workbook, that must be coming from _somewhere_; I don't think Excel is making up data because you caught it playing games and it turned on the boss screen.

Comment: @sk11 my workbook is having 150 worksheets, count variable gives me the output as total number of worksheets present in the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

1. instead `excel.visible = 1` should be `excel.Visible = 1`,
2. instead `excel.Workbooks.open('<PATH TO EXCEL>')` - `excel.Workbooks.Open('<PATH TO EXCEL>')`
3. instead `wb.Sheets.count` - `wb.Sheets.Count`,
4. instead `wb.Sheets[ 89 ].name` - `wb.Sheets[ 89 ].Name`

This is fixed version (works for me):

```
import win32com.client
dispatch = win32com.client.Dispatch
excel = dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = 1
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('<PATH TO EXCEL>')
count = wb.Sheets.Count # count stores total number of worksheets present
print count
ws_name = wb.Sheets[ 89 ].Name

print ws_name
```

Comment: Have you tried the above code with more than 85 worksheets in a single workbook; because i am facing problem while reading sheet name if i am putting value which is more than 85 in **ws_name = wb.Sheets[ 89 ].Name** ??

Comment: Yes, I tried, and it works well. Can you give a link to your excel file?

Comment: Now its working for me as well; also this python code works without making any changes in my code as u mentioned in your answer.